# My Brainfuck interpreter in F#

Tags: f#, interpreter, brainfuck

I'm very new to functional world. I've written a simple brainfuck interpreter as my first F# program.

What I would like to know:

- Am I using the right data structure for each situation?
- Is my code easy to understand?
- Is my code style similar to common F# codes (naming, organization etc)?
- Is my code "very declarative" or I'm still thinking in the imperative way?

What is not so relevant:

- Performance (but if I've made something very bad, let me now!)
- More features

Obs.: I assume input is always a valid brainfuck code and that's ok to me.

```
open System
open System.IO

let getValue (position:int) (memory:Map<int, int>) =
    match Map.tryFind position memory with
    | None  -> 0
    | value -> value.Value

let calcAccumulator (acc:int) (instruction:char) (search:char) (miss:char) =
    match instruction with
    | x when x = search -> acc+1
    | x when x = miss   -> acc-1
    | _ -> acc

let rec findMatch (code:string) (search:char) (miss:char) (inc:int) (current:int) (acc:int) =
    let instruction = code.[current]

    match instruction, acc with
    | x, 0 when x = search -> current+1
    | _    -> findMatch code search miss inc (current+inc) (calcAccumulator acc instruction search miss)

let updateMemory (instruction:char) (position:int) (memory:Map<int, int>) =
    let oldValue = getValue position memory
    let newValue =
        match instruction with
        | '+' -> oldValue + 1
        | '-' -> oldValue - 1
        | ',' -> Console.ReadKey().KeyChar |> Convert.ToInt32
        | _   -> oldValue

    Map.add position newValue memory

let updateOutput (instruction) (value:int) =
    if instruction = '.'
    then Console.Write ((char) value)

let updatePosition (instruction:char) (position:int) =
    match instruction with
    | '>' -> position+1
    | '<' -> position-1
    | _   -> position

let updateIndex (code:string) (index:int) (value:int) =
    match code.[index], value with
    | '[', 0 -> findMatch code ']' '[' 1 (index+1) 0
    | ']', x when x <> 0 -> findMatch code '[' ']' -1 (index-1) 0
    | _      -> index+1

let rec interpretHelper (code:string) (index:int) (memory:Map<int, int>) (position:int) =
    match code.Length with
    | x when x = index  -> memory
    | _ ->
        let instruction = code.[index]
        let newPosition = updatePosition instruction position
        let newMemory = updateMemory instruction position memory
        let newIndex = updateIndex code index (getValue position memory)
        updateOutput instruction (getValue position memory)
        interpretHelper code newIndex newMemory newPosition

let interpret (code:string) =
    interpretHelper code 0 Map.empty 0

let options (args:string array) =
    let pathToFile = args.[0]
    let showMemory = 
        match args with
        | [| _ ; "-memory" |] -> true
        | _                   -> false

    pathToFile, showMemory

let onlyCode (text:string) =
    let validInstructions = "+-.,][<>".ToCharArray()

    String.filter (fun x -> Array.contains x validInstructions) text

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let pathToFile, showMemory = options args
    let code = onlyCode (IO.File.ReadAllText pathToFile)
    let memory = interpret code

    if showMemory
    then Map.iter (fun a b -> printf "\n%3d: %d" a b) memory

    0
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Richard_Grant Make the code easier to understand, more idiomatic and elegant. The goal is not performance, it's readability.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the language. I am actually trying to learn from reading your code. Give me a few moments and i will throw out some suggestions.

Comment: I got: init.fsx(75,12): error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'filter' is not defined

Comment: Oh, it's strange. Are you using Visual Studio 2015? It works nice if I create a new F# Console Application project and paste the code into Program.fs.

Comment: Oh tarder sauce... you're in Visual Studio, its probably the compiler. I will have to wait till later tonight to test it. I was attempting to test it on ubuntu

Comment: I used [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Hello_World.21), they have some scripts to test. I also used some examples I found elsewhere on internet but the wiki will give you a good amount of tests.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I just didn't see your reply. Please, next time, use a nick in this way, for example: `@Foggy Finder,...`  Then there will be a notification.

Comment: I'll try to write an answer in 1-2 days.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, can you hear me? :D

Comment: I`m really sorry. I was without internet connection within a few days. Now I fix it. I need to do some work and then I'll come back here.

Comment: I would like to clarify some details to improve my answer. If you don't mind, I would like to continue in [SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me make a few comments:

1. F# has a good system of type inference. You don't need to specify the type explicitly, the compiler in many cases will do it for you. You can read more about it [here](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-inference/).
2. In function `getValue`. Usually, matched with None|Some value:

   ```
   match Map.tryFind position memory with
       | None  -> 0
       | Some value -> value
   ```

   Although you can rewrite this code with using [defaultArg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.defaultarg%5b%27t%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)

   ```
   let getValue position memory =
       defaultArg (Map.tryFind position memory) 0
   ```
3. In function `updateIndex` you can check the value with 0 in match:

   ```
   let updateIndex (code:string) index value =
       match code.[index], value = 0 with
       | '[', true  -> findMatch code ']' '['  1 (index + 1) 0
       | ']', false -> findMatch code '[' ']' -1 (index - 1) 0
       | _      -> index + 1
   ```
4. The helper functions better write as nested:

   ```
   let interpret (code:string) =
       let rec interpretHelper index memory position =
   ```

   You can read more about it [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/organizing-functions/)
5. In function `interpretHelper`, use if-then-else instead of PM:

   ```
   let rec interpretHelper index memory position =
       if code |> String.length = index  then
           memory
       else ...
   ```